# Display sql database values in textboxes using the session id

Tags: vb.net, sessionid

I am stuck at a situation where i want to display the data in sql server database into the feilds on web page when user login their account.
So for that i have wrriten a code in a class file.

```
    Public Function FetchResult() As DataTable
    Dim str As String =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbSurvey").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(str)

    Dim fetch As String = "Select * from table_name"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(fetch, conn)

    Dim objAdpt As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim objDt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    objAdpt.Fill(objDt)

    Return objDt
End Function
```

and calling this function in the login button click. so that after user login, they can see their existing information

```
Dim dta As DataTable = obj.FetchSurveyResult
        If MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2 Then
              txtBox.Text = dta.Rows(0)("Location1")
        End If
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Data is not displayed in the feilds when i am logging in the account.